# Returning value from service to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameter-passing

In my view on `input[submit]` click I execute function from controller which execute another function from service.

controller.js
`colorCheckerService.colorCheck(vm.color_field);`

this starts whenever user click submit button. Next after color is checked I execute another function from other service:

```
this.colorCheck = function(color_field) {
    console.log('im working colorCheck function in service');
    switch (color_field.charAt(0)) {
        case 'r':
            console.log('its RGB');
            colorChangerService.colorChange.fromRGB.prepareAndExecute(color_field);
            break;
```

So the line `colorChangerService.colorChange.fromRGB.prepareAndExecute(color_field);` is in service1 and it's starting service2

```
toHEX: {
    supportFunc: function(number) {
        var hex = number.toString(16);
        return hex.length == 1 ? '0' + hex : hex;
    },
    convert: function(r, g, b) {
        var lol = '#' + this.supportFunc(r) + this.supportFunc(g) + this.supportFunc(b);
        console.log(lol);
    }
},
prepareAndExecute: function(color_field) {
    // preparing
    var numbers = color_field.match(/\d+/g);
    if(numbers.length == 3) {
        this.toHEX.convert(+numbers[0], +numbers[1], +numbers[2]);
    } else {
        alert('wrong RGB number format');
    }
```

This is basically converting RGB to HEX. It's working good, it finish working at line `console.log(lol);`. `lol` variable contains converted color.

The way from beggining to end this `console.log` method is long, in brief it is going: view (click) -> controller -> service1 -> service2.

Now the question is, how can I pass this variable `lol` back to controller so I can finally display this converted color in view?

I already have tried with promise but with no luck. It would be much easier to use promise if I would have only one service.

Comment: To pass a value back from a function, use a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Comment: You tried something with no luck but you don't show us the code that had no luck. Unfortunately we can't fix code that we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you had your code in a playground (jsfiddle, codepen, etc...), so I could respond with a good code example. It sounds like you need a service member/property for `lol`, that you set in the `convert` method, and a method that gets that value so it can be retrieved in the controller.

### Service

```
 toHEX: {
        supportFunc: function(number) {
            var hex = number.toString(16);
            return hex.length == 1 ? '0' + hex : hex;
        },
        lol: "",
        convert: function(r, g, b) {
            this.lol = '#' + this.supportFunc(r) + this.supportFunc(g) + this.supportFunc(b);
            console.log(lol);
        }
    },
    getLol: function() { return this.toHEX.lol; }
```

And then call `colorChangerService.colorChange.fromRGB.getLol()` in the controller where it's needed.